# Calculating Flux across a spherical surface in a vector field (Newtonian Gravity)

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

The question I am working on gives the Poisson Equation for Newtonian Gravity  $∇⃗ ∙ ⃗(⃗) = −4(⃗) $ with the mass density function $(⃗) =0/(1 + (⁄0)^2)$ and asks for the flux of the gravitational acceleration across a spherical surface with radius $r$.

Using the divergence theorem, so far I have:

$ \oint \oint  \overrightarrow{g} (\overrightarrow{r}) \cdot ds =  \iiint \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{g} (\overrightarrow{r}) dV$

$= -4\pi G \rho 0 \iiint 1/(1+(r/r0)^2) dV$

However I don't know how to solve the integral I have arrived at. I thought about changing it to spherical coordinates but am not sure if that would help?

Comment: Please note your mass density function uses $r$ notation and the radius of the spherical surface is also $r$. Either you (/the question) are using same notations which is confusing or the density is really not changing at different points within a sphere of given radius.

Answer (score 1):

"Slicing" along the z-axis yields circles of radius $\sqrt{r^2-z^2}$, so parameterizing in terms of $r$ and $\theta$:
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r}{1+(\frac{r}{r_0})^2}d\theta dr
$$
So the entire integral should be:
$$
\iiint\nabla\cdot\vec{g}(\vec{r})dV=-4\pi G\rho_0\int_{-r}^r\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r}{1+(\frac{r}{r_0})^2}d\theta dr dz
$$
Which can be solved with integration by parts and partial fractions.